# Reply All with Body of Top Email in Inbox

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook

I'm attempting to create a VBA script to reply all to the most recent (top) email in my inbox.

I'm using the following code and am very close, but it need to it to default to the top email in my inbox rather that the one currently selected:

```
Sub my_test(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objItem As Object

Dim mail As MailItem
Dim replyall As MailItem

Dim templateItem As MailItem

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
    
        Set mail = objItem
        Set replyall = mail.replyall
                
        Set templateItem = CreateItemFromTemplate("Template")
        
        With replyall
            .HTMLBody = templateItem.HTMLBody & .HTMLBody
            .Display
        End With
        
    End If
    
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it need to it to default to the top email in my inbox rather that the one currently selected

The top email depends on the sorting order used for the view or folder in Outlook. Typically items are sorted by the [RecievedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property which returns a date indicating the date and time at which the item was received. So, you can sort the `Items` collection using the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method and get the first or last one which will be the top item in the view.

```
Sub SortByRecievedDate() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Object
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
 
 myItems.Sort "[RecievedTime]", False 
 
 For Each myItem In myItems 
   MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
 Next myItem 
End Sub
```

But ideally you need to get the sorting order from the [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view) object in Outlook. The `View` object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data. You can be interested in the [View.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter) property which returns or sets a string value that represents the filter for a view. The [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.xml) definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.